# Multiple subscribers in NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus, publish-subscribe

I'm getting started with NServiceBus and have a question about the Pubsub sample.

My intention was to have multiple instances of Publisher1 running and receiving the message sent from the publisher. I also hacked the Publisher to only send messages of the eventMessage type.

But if I start the publisher and three instances of Subscriber1, only one of them gets the message at a time.

why is that? Is it a config setting or something else?

This is what I've tried which returns an exception "Exception when starting endpoint, error has been logged. Reason: Cannot configure property before the component has been configured. Please call 'Configure' first.":

```
using NServiceBus;

namespace Subscriber1
{
    public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server
    {
    }

    public class OverrideInputQueue : IWantCustomInitialization
    {
        public void Init()
        {
            Configure
                .Instance
                .Configurer
                .ConfigureProperty<NServiceBus.Config.MsmqTransportConfig>(t => t.InputQueue, "testQueue");
        }
    }
}
```

/J

Answer (score 1):

NServiceBus assumes that you have one input queue per process. Make sure that each of your subscribers are configured with a unique input queue. If not all three will be polling the same queue producing the behavior you're describing.

To do this you would probably have to copy paste sub1 to 3 different folders, modfying the app.config and start them up.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it does. But then I have to set the queue programatically somehow. Right?? I found something like this:

 Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureProperty<MsmqTransport>(t =>
 t.InputQueue, yourDynamicQueue);

.. but couldn't get it to work.

Any tips??

Comment: Yes if you can't copy paste the folder and modify the separate app.config's you'd have to set it programmatically.

Take a look here:
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/6378

Can you give some more details on what you're trying to achieve with all this? 

If it's about distributing load you should look at using the distributor:
http://nservicebus.com/Distributor.aspx

Comment: What I want is to have multiple instances of the same client all receiving messages when certain events happen. Maybe when someone creates a customer, all clients gets a news flash about it.

Comment: But since I'm just starting maybe the pubsub sample isn't the right "template" for this scenario.

Comment: You need to programmatically set the input queue in a IWantCustomInitialization class that is different from the IConfigureThisEndpoint class.

Comment: Like above where I have the endpoint class and a OverrideInputQueue class which implements IWantCustomInitialization. They are separate classes.

Comment: I did succeed in running the sample when I changed the above Init code to:             Configure
                .Instance
                .Configurer
                .ConfigureComponent<NServiceBus.Config.MsmqTransportConfig>(NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.ComponentCallModelEnum.None)
                .ConfigureProperty(t => t.InputQueue, "testQueue");

But it still uses the InputQueue specified in the config file.

Comment: You need to configure the MsmqTransport itself as follows: Configure.Instance.ConfigureComponent<MsmqTransport>(t => t.InputQueue, yourDynamicQueue); rather than MsmqTransportConfig.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this-

```
Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureProperty<NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Msmq.MsmqTransport>(msmq => msmq.InputQueue, "SomeQueueHere");
```

Make sure you use **MsmqTransport** and not **MsmqTransportConfig** as you mentioned.